# Combining Dates Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 115 columns of dates

```
1/22/20 1/23/20 1/24/20 1/25/20  1/26/20 1/27/20 1/28/20 1/29/20 1/30/20
0.        0.       0      0.        5.      2.     1.      0         0
```

How do I get all the columns into one column I tried

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

But this does not work, I am trying to get the data frame to look like

```
Date       Value
1/22/20.     0
1/23/20      0
1/24/20      0
1/25/20      0
1/26/20      5
1/27/20      2
1/28/20      1
1/29/20      0
1/30/20      0
```

Comment: why did the value 5 come for 25th jan 2020?

Comment: @anky that was a mistake I apologize

Comment: did you try `df.melt()` ?

Comment: Would I do df.melt() and put in the range of columns?

Comment: Unpivotting in power query is equivalent to using the melt function. Check the docs :)